# Current Transducer Usage

Tags: current, transducer

I'm just a bit confused about this current transducer/sensor 
https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/current-transducers/1383472/

Datasheet: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/15c5/0900766b815c5532.pdf

I can't seem to figure out the reason for the reference voltage.
Is the output voltage = to -2V when -250A is being pushed and = to +2V when +250A is being pushed?
And is it linearly scaled? I.e would +1V mean +125A?

How exactly is the output working here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference voltage is what the transducer produces on its output when measuring 0A.
So if 250A measured gives +2V out, then what you'll actually see at the output is 4.5V  (2.5 + 2).
Similarly, for -250A you'll see 0.5V (2.5 - 2).

It appears that you can also drive the reference voltage to a value of your choosing, so you can set the output voltage for 0A to whatever level is convenient for your application.

Yes, the scaling is linear (at least within the limits of error shown in the datasheet).